# iOS Deployment Target & Block Support

Tags: ios4, objective-c-blocks, deployment-target

If I use blocks in my code and set the iOS Deployment Target to less than iOS 4.0, will the app still work on devices that are running an iOS less than 4.0?

The Base SDK is set to Latest iOS (iOS 4.3) obviously.

Answer (score 2):

From the apple documentation:

> Blocks are available in GCC and Clang as shipped with the Mac OS X v10.6 Xcode developer tools. You can use blocks with Mac OS X v10.6 and later, and iOS 4.0 and later.

So the answer is no, you can't use blocks when deploying to 3.2 targets.